# Ionic Back button is not shown

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello I am trying to Customize Ionic Header. Code is shown below:

```
 <ion-header-bar>
  <div class="buttons">
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="buttons">
   <span class="icons_all store">
                   <a href="#" class="ion-search"> </a>
                   <a href="#"> <img src="img/assets/location.png"></a>
                   <a href="#" class="ion-android-more-vertical"></a>
   </span>
   </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
```

Problem is when i try to redirect page to new page . Back button for above header which is also called on other pages , doesn't show .

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
```

As per the document http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavBackButton/

Comment: Where do i need to add this?